# How to find Product Images depending on the Alt tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, shopify, activeresource

I have been able to set the Alt tag when uploading an image to a product, via an html form.

```
images = params[:images] || nil

if images
 images.each do |image|
      a = ShopifyAPI::Image.new
      a.prefix_options = {:product_id => params[:product_id]}
      a.metafields = [{:key => 'alt', :value => 'Cake', :value_type => "string", :namespace =>  "tags"}]
      a.attachment = Base64.encode64(image.read)
      a.filename = image.original_filename
      a.save
 end
else
.
.
.
```

But when it comes to retrieving the images for a product, where alt='Cake', I cannot seem to figure it out. I have tried searching the Metafields via the ShopifyAPI console, with no joy.

---

Would be nice if it were this easy...

```
a = ShopifyAPI::Image.where(alt: 'Cake', product_id: 245512249)
```

or better...

```
a = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(245512249)
b = a.images.select { |image| image.alt == 'Cake' }
```

or...

```
a = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(245512249)
a.images.each do |image|
  b << image if image.alt == 'Cake'
end
```

Comment: When you have a product via one api call, you get all it's images. It would then be trivial to iterate the images looking for the one you're interested in. That is much simpler and more reliable than searching for an image based on the contents of an alt tag.

Comment: @DavidLazar Thanks, but I've tried that way as well. Problem is, is the images don't have an alt attribute. They seem to rely on the link table Metafields - I tried seeing what metafields exist, and there are none that relate to image

Comment: Ya.. alt tags are a metafield and since those resources are extra... you cannot search them without searching all the images... lucky you. Using alt tags for logic is probably a bad idea anyway. I would leave them for their sole purpose of explaining an image for SEO.

Comment: @DavidLazar Would you know where the 'alt' tag metafield resides? It is weird that they seem to not exist via the Shop metafields or Product metafields. How would you suggest I tag each image, to then be searchable upon?

Comment: They're attached directly to the images I would think. Why search images anyway? For what purpose would you search an alt tag?

Comment: It's for isolating the images into a separate collection/album on the product page, from the other product images. Had an idea to use the image filename as an identifier like `image.key contains 'cake'`, but the liquid does not have `image.key`

Comment: Stick with filename keys then and avoid the complexity of metafields. Your code will be easier to maintain and you eliminate a lot of needless complexity. Leave alt tags alone for SEO. Just my 0.02 from having done what you want dozens of times... or more

Comment: Doesn't looks like I can access the filename (key) when querying the images for the product, but I should be able to parse the file source string (src). Liquid wise, I cannot print out the filename, so I will stick to using the image 'alt' tags to filter. Thanks though, I have something now to play with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of recalling Product Images depending on the Alt tag; the ShopifyAPI does not allow for it.

---

Saying that though, here is a trade secret...

Just tag on the value of the Alt tag to the filename of the image.

```
images = params[:images] || nil

if images
 images.each do |image|
      a = ShopifyAPI::Image.new
      a.prefix_options = {:product_id => params[:product_id]}
      a.metafields = [{:key => 'alt', :value => 'Cake', :value_type => "string", :namespace =>  "tags"}]
      a.attachment = Base64.encode64(image.read)
      a.filename = 'Cake_'+image.original_filename
      a.save
 end
else
.
.
.
```

That way, you can filter the Product Images via the string value 'Cake_' on the ':src' attribute.

```
@product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(params[:id])

@product.images.each do |image|
  if image.attributes[:src].include?('Cake_')
    .
    .
    .
  end
end
```

Hope that helps!